# Detecting when user lifts finger off UIScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to detect when the user lifts their finger in a `UITableView` while they scroll, so in the `UIScrollView` delegate method `scrollViewDidScroll:`

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
    // Some code…


    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.state == .Ended
    {
        NSLog("ENDED")
    }
}
```

To me this sounds like it should work, so when I investigated further and logged what states happen at this point, the only two logs were `Changed` and `Possible`.

To my understanding `Ended` should happen before possible if the gesture has ended.

Apple docs:

> The gesture recognizer has received touches recognized as the end of a continuous gesture. It sends its action message (or messages) at the next cycle of the run loop and resets its state to UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible.

What exactly is going on here? And how do I find when the user lifts their finger off my `UITableView` during a scroll?

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` doesn’t fire when the scroll view isn’t being dragged, it’s actually when the user lifts their finger. This is where `Ended` is fired.

Comment: Additionally, if you are wanting to deal with multi-touch you can analyze `scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.numberOfTouches` to further detect finger(s) being lifted.

Answer (score 1):

You can determine when a finger is lifted by implementing the `-scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:` `UIScrollViewDelegate` method. No need to inspect the state of the underlying gesture recognizer.

Comment: Yeah, just found out the hard way, haha. Oh well, I blame the unclear method name